# HTML Form Linking

Tags: html, forms

As a newbie to HTML, I am seeking your help and guidance.

I am trying to create a page which will have only **two Buttons** like: 
**Create User** and **Log In**

Depending on which button is clicked a form will be processed. 
It's similar to a concept of *Register* or *LogIn*.

PS: I am trying to use java for the script part

Please Guide me to achieve the above mentioned scenario

Comment: Use a button of type `submit` for Login and use an anchor tag that redirects to the registration form page. That way you will have two action items that do two different things. No need of javascript too.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Create User">` and 
`<input type="submit" value="Log In">`, then check the value

Comment: It's unclear what is your level in HTML & Javascript, because such a thing as you ask is extremely simple to do, it appears you should first learn the basics and then try to apply them, reading some tutorials perhaps and only asking "how to do it" as a last resort. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your descriptions you have a page with only two buttons in it. So there is no form in this page but then when you click on any of buttons they lead you to another page with a form.
then you can have a  tag like this:

```html
<a href="">
<div style="width: 60px; height: 30px; border: solid 1px; text-align: center">Log In</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will send different data to the server, depending on which button was clicked

```js
var formElm = document.forms[0];

formElm.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  return false; // disable normal form submit so the page won't refresh
})

// when button number #1 gets clicked, send the form to the server
formElm.querySelector('.do1').addEventListener('click', function(){
  fetch('/url',{ method:'POST', body:new FormData(formElm) })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', JSON.parse(data))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('request failed', error)
    })
});

// when button number #1 gets clicked, do something else..you choose.
formElm.querySelector('.do2').addEventListener('click', function(){
  // send something else to the server
  // ...
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='something' value='foo'>
  <button type='button' class='do1'>button 1</button>
  <button type='button' class='do2'>button 2</button>
</form>
```